# Where can I find an implementation of Hinton's original Boltzmann Machine?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, autoencoders

I've been trying to implement the Boltzmann machine 4-2-4 encoder that appeared in [A Learning Algorithm for Boltzmann Machines](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1207/s15516709cog0901_7/asset/s15516709cog0901_7.pdf;jsessionid=E5E7C5C7C1AC1C0E5DA2FE597DB70E2A.f03t02?v=1&t=hvpyew22&s=b4b4a8c8bf28b6dff5cfe710709dde92a2ba180b). but I am unable to find clear pseudocode for doing it or more specific details. I have tried "Neural networks: algorithms, applications, and programming techniques" and [Fausett](http://books.google.com.mx/books?id=ONylQgAACAAJ&dq=Laurene%20Fausett&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kjyFU5j6AsKryASYx4GYCA&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA) books so far. Where can I find an implementation of the encoder or more specific details about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally implemented the Boltzmann machine for 4-2-4 encoder problem using several descriptions. You can find my implementation in this [blog post](http://gorayni.blogspot.com/2014/06/boltzmann-machines.html).

Comment: Just a note: the $\LaTeX$ code on your page isn't rendering on my computer, it's just source code. Not sure if it's because I'm using an old browser on an old computer or what.

Comment: It is a problem of loading correctly the MathJax libraries on blogspot. It seems that I managed to solve the Latex rendering issue using the advice on this page [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mathjax-users/blogspot/mathjax-users/Jh_4kWotsS8/Jq5fD0eci48J), hope it works for you.

Comment: Still no luck, but MathJax seems to have stopped working on other sites as well for me so I don't think you can fix it, unless you want to buy me a new laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Salakhutdinov was a student of Hinton who has since moved to Microsoft.

http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rsalakhu/DBM.html <-- here is working MatLab code for an RBM.

It's a bit of a mess, I'm a week into rewriting it. If I haven't updated this answer within a month, someone ping me and I will upload my rewrite to GitHub.